# how to update a highcart column chart on a button click

Tags: javascript, ajax, highcharts

i have a column chart, and i need to refresh (redraw) it, on button click.

this is the code i load when i load the page:

```
    function setParetoChart(data) {
    $('#liveChart2').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Detail'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Detail'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Totale Detail'
            }

        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: "pointer",
                point: {....
                        },
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> del Totale<br/>Numero Pezzi Scarti: <span style="color:{point.color}"></span>: <b>{point.scarti}</b> '
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Details',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: data
        }]
    });

}
```

now, on button click, i get data from an ajax function, that returns an array of objects, in this way;

```
drilldown: 'var1'
name: 'var1'
scarts: 15,
y; 15
```

.. and with an array of that objects, i need to redraw my column chart..

Answer (score 1):

This thread might help...
[Lazy Highcharts drilldown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26801793/lazy-highcharts-drilldown)

The soultion implements lazy drill down highcharts using Ajax.